# Find element in page with class XYZ

Tags: javascript

I am running a script as follows:

```
Galleria.run(".showcase");
```

The problem is when there is no element with class ".showcase" a message is rendered on the page.

How can I run this code if an element with class .showcase is found in the page?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.showcase') && Galleria.run(".showcase");`

Comment: You appear to be using some framework but haven't told us which one. This could be useful information.

Comment: if you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**getElementsByClassName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('showcase');

if(elements.length){
    Galleria.run(".showcase");
}
```